# Qwik useState Error with Supabase Auth Component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, lazy-loading, qwik

I know there's not a lot of [Qwik](https://qwik.builder.io/) content on here, but I was wondering if anyone who fundamentally understands component rendering can help me with my question. I am trying to place a [Supabase Auth UI](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/auth-ui) into my `component$` function like this:

```
import { component$ } from "@builder.io/qwik";

import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";
import { Auth } from '@supabase/auth-ui-react'

const supabase = createClient(`my-url`, `my-key`)

export default component$(() => {
    return (
        <Auth supabaseClient={supabase} />
    );
})
```

which produces this error:

```
Internal server error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
  File: /dist-dev/tsc-out/packages/qwik/src/core/util/implicit_dollar.js:1461:26
      at useState (C:\Users\isaac\Downloads\VS Code\planner\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:1622:21)
      at k (file:///C:/Users/isaac/Downloads/VS%20Code/planner/node_modules/@supabase/auth-ui-react/dist/index.es.js:1211:48)
      at invoke (../../../dist-dev/tsc-out/packages/qwik/src/core/util/implicit_dollar.js:1461:26)
      at renderNode (../../../dist-dev/tsc-out/packages/qwik/src/core/util/implicit_dollar.js:4129:17)
      at processData$1 (../../../dist-dev/tsc-out/packages/qwik/src/core/util/implicit_dollar.js:4143:16)
      at ../../../dist-dev/tsc-out/packages/qwik/src/core/util/implicit_dollar.js:4210:26
      at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
      at walkChildren (../../../dist-dev/tsc-out/packages/qwik/src/core/util/implicit_dollar.js:4195:21)
      at renderNodeVirtual (../../../dist-dev/tsc-out/packages/qwik/src/core/util/implicit_dollar.js:3688:21)
      at renderNode (../../../dist-dev/tsc-out/packages/qwik/src/core/util/implicit_dollar.js:4120:16) (x2)
```

Does this have to do with lazy-loading and `useState` being weird at the time of this component rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use React component without wrapping it with [qwikify$()](https://qwik.builder.io/docs/integrations/react/#qwikify)

Here is a qwik supabase auth working [example](https://github.com/gioboa/qwik-supabase-auth)